# How to make my script auto-run when a USB is plugged in?

Tags: python, windows-10, autorun

I have the following python file in my usb:

```
Game.py
```

I want to make it run automatically when I plug in the USB.

I wrote the following in notepad:

```
[autorun]

shellexecute=Game.py
action=MyProgram Open Program
```

and saved it as `autorun.inf`.

But it does not run and my computer displays:

> There is a problem with this drive. Scan and fix it now?

Whats wrong and how can I fix this?

**Note:**
I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Have tried letting it scan and fix the problem? If not, why?

Comment: I have and it reports no problem every time.However , if I remove the `autorun.inf`, there is no error.

Comment: Autorun on USB devices is disabled in modern versions of Windows because it was a common attack vector. You might be able to turn it back on, but that would only work for computers you control. Your error message maybe because you didn't use the "Safely Remove Hardware" notification icon before unplugging it from your computer.

Comment: It may not be enabled. See article [_How to enable, configure and set AutoPlay defaults in Windows 10_](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/set-autoplay-defaults-windows-10).

Comment: Not a Python question, but a Windows one, most frequently caused by unproper unmounting. Eject the drive in Windows (Safely remove hardware or some similar option) before unplugging it to prevent this kind of error. That said, most of the time a scan with checkdisk suffices to fix it. Start the command prompt (cmd) as administrator and type: `chkdsk driveletter: /f/r`, let it finish and test if the error was resolved. If that still doesn't help, check the Device Manger, expand the Universal serial bus controllers and uninstall all USB ports, then restart to let Windows reinstall them.

Comment: @RossRidge , thanks for the information! 
martineau Is there no other way to make my script self executable?

Comment: Not that I know of...unless burning it onto a CD/DVD is an option (assuming those are handled different from USB flash drives). IMO having a restriction like this make sense if you think about it (for the reason @RossRidge points out).

Comment: Hmm...thanks @martineau!

Comment: Here's [another article](http://windowsreport.com/disable-autorun-windows-10/) about making registry changes that might make it possible. Although the article's about disabling the feature, it looks like the procedure could be done in reverse. Obviously, something like that would have to been done ahead of time by someone with administrative privileges on the system.

Comment: I looked around a bit, since it's news to me that Win 7 and higher disables the autorun.inf for USB devices. http://www.visualdesigning.com/articles/how-to-create-autorun-usb-drive/ claims to have a solution for this. I can't test it, but it might solve the other part of your problem. A word of warning though, this might damage your USB device, so don't test it with your new 64GB one.

Comment: @Telefonmann , that looks promising.Gonna try it after my high school exams...2 more months!

Answer (score 1):

hi i am a beginner myself but this should do the trick

```
[autorun]
;Open=YOURAPP.exe
ShellExecute=YOURAPP.exe
UseAutoPlay=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use [autorun] or autorun.inf files on Windows anymore. Microsoft disabled this in Windows 7 so that viruses can't spread easily.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).